# Does jQuery offset(); work on td cells?

Tags: jquery, html-table, offset

I'm trying to have a tool tip pop-up just slightly to the left of a couple of td cells in a table:

```
$('table.seafood td.prod4').hover(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $("div.peekSeafood4").fadeIn(200);
    $("div.peekSeafood4").css('left', offset.left + 'px');
}, function() {
    $("div.peekSeafood4").fadeOut(200);
});
```

It's not working, throwing the tooltips far off to the side of the screen.

Does `offset();` not work with td cells/tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `offset()` works with table cells.  [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DfGBh/) will show you it working at the most basic level.

I suspect the problem lies with `$("div.peekSeafood4")`, which will be positioned relative to its `offsetParent` element - you might need to make sure that the `offsetParent` for the matching element is the `<body>` element.

As @patrick_dw pointed out earlier, there's also the possibility that [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) would give you the correct results, depending on where your tool tip pop-up is placed in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure who it was but someone suggested using .position(); rather than offset(); and that in fact worked (the ocmment has unfortunately been deleted).

Comment: @Yahreen: it was [patrick dw](http://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/patrick-dw). Perhaps he'll see this comment and undelete his answer.

Comment: How can I go about calculating the width of the div? I've used .width(); in this example but it apparently doesnttake into consideration the padding: http://jsfiddle.net/dfbEV/

Comment: @Yahreen: use `outerWidth()`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. One final question: How can I position this div, say, with 1em top margin respective of where I hover?

Comment: @Yahreen: Sorry, I deleted because I realized I didn't have enough info to know if it was the right solution, and I had to break away, so I just +'d this one since it was dealing with the possibility. I think Andy E has you covered. @Andy: I think I'll leave mine deleted, so if `.position()` is helpful here, by all means add it to your answer. :o)

Comment: This question & the comments have helped me. Although I have a weird issue where I'm trying to get the offset of whatever TD I mouseenter, and the first value is always wrong, but mouseentering subsequent TDs sets it right. Fun stuff.